# Nav menu not shrinking on scroll outside of Codepen

Tags: javascript, html, css

Header not shrinking on scroll.

Tried finding the error in js and css but can't seem to find the problem.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
        $('header').addClass('black');
    }
    else {
        $('header').removeClass('black');
    }
})
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".menu h4").click(function(){
        $("nav ul").toggleClass("active")
    })
})
```

Works on Codepen but when create a html file with the code and link the html file to the css and js file in separate files the nav doesn't shrink on scroll.

Comment: https://codepen.io/artistarj/pen/xJLKWx

Comment: Hi Matthew, could you post where you're linking your CSS and JS?

Comment: Hi Halden,
I have created these files and copied the code from the codepen link for css and js.

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/index.js"></script>

Comment: `if ($(window).scrollTop())` should you not have an equals somewhere here, also you only seem to add and remove a colour class - without seeing your css it's impossible to tell what adding and removing that class does.  Please create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem

Comment: Try putting this `script` tag in before your custom JS. `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: Hi Pete, it was the problem Halden and Ian mentioned Codepen includes Jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript code is using jQuery, which Codepen automatically imports. In order to have the same functionality elsewhere, you will need to [import jQuery](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/) yourself.

Comment: Thank you Ian. Much appreciated.